# Including a specific Joomla module into a template

Tags: php, joomla, include, joomla-template, joomla-module

I am at the copy-paste stadium of `PHP` coding, so I would like to be pointed in the right direction here.

On this page:

http://anansi.dk/index.php?option=com_configbox&view=category&prod_id=2&cat_id=27&Itemid=227&lang=da

I am trying to load a module called `mod_hot_joomla_carousel_pro` at the bottom - beneath the other elements. The way I am trying to do this is by using the same strip of PHP used for including the price module, inside the template. It looks like this:

```
<?php 
   include_once(KPATH_ROOT.DS.'modules'.DS.'mod_hot_joomla_carousel_pro'.DS.'mod_hot_joomla_carousel_pro.php');
?>
```

It works - sort of - you can see the arrows. But how do I get it to load the specific module  instance, with the pictures and all?

Best, Astrid

Comment: Any reason you're bypassing Joomla's built-in module placement mechanisms?

Comment: It just hadn't crossed my mind - thanks for the tip! I was too keen on horsing around with php 8-)

Answer (score 0):

You want to display module on the page? Better add position of module and adjust module on this position `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-0" />`
But if you want include module, better do it in such way

```
<?php
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_hot_joomla_carousel_pro',$title);
//get and update params
$params = new JRegistry;
$params->loadString($module->params);
$params->set('some_param_of_module',$some_value);
//render module
$renderer = $doc->loadRenderer('module');
$content = $renderer->render($module, array('params'=> $params));
print $content;
?>
```

Comment: oh, sorry. stupid copy-paste :). i use (sometimes) such way of connection of module from j1.5

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It works now - I use tha Joomla built-in module placement feature instead. It just had not crossed my mind :-!